# Numbered question paper from a question bank

Tags: numbering

I have seen a method in [Generate exam from a question bank?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174872/generate-exam-from-a-question-bank)
to generate a question paper from a question bank.
I have a question: How can we enumerate (I need question numbers successively)
the questions?

Answer (score 2):

If the aim is nothing more than to have a single counter which increments every time a new question is printed, we can just add a new counter `\newcounter{numberedquestions}` and print and increment that every time a question is printed by replacing the following from [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174962/106162) to [Generate exam from a question bank?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174872/106162)

```
\ifnum\value{questionblock}=\randomquestion 
  \par% Start new paragraph
  \BODY% Print question
\fi
```

with

```
\ifnum\value{questionblock}=\randomquestion 
  \par% Start new paragraph
  \stepcounter{numberedquestions}
  \arabic{numberedquestions}. \BODY% Print question
\fi
```

where each time a question is printed (the `\BODY`), the question is prefixed by `\arabic{numberedquestions}.` (or whatever format is desired for the numbering) to give a question number and the counter is incremented to keep track of the number of questions printed.

With the above change to [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174962/106162) we have

```
%From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174962/ with minor changes to number the output questions
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}% Just for this example
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bankA.tex}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 1
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 2
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 3
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 4
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 5
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 6
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 7
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 8
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 9
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 10
\end{questionblock}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{catchfile,environ,tikz}

\makeatletter% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109619/5764
\def\declarenumlist#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname{#3}%
  \count@\@ne
  \loop
    \expandafter\edef
    \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\endcsname
      {\the\count@}
    \ifnum\count@<#3\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat}
\def\prunelist#1{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname
          {\the\numexpr\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname-1\relax}
  \count@\pgfmath@randomtemp 
  \loop
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\let
    \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\numexpr\count@+1\relax\endcsname
    \ifnum\count@<\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname\relax
      \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat}
\makeatother

% Define how each questionblock should be handled
\newcounter{questionblock}
\newcounter{totalquestions}
\NewEnviron{questionblock}{}%

\newcounter{numberedquestions}

\newcommand{\randomquestionsfrombank}[2]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\bank}{#1}{}% Read the entire bank of questions into \bank
  \setcounter{totalquestions}{0}% Reset total questions counters  ***
  \RenewEnviron{questionblock}{\stepcounter{totalquestions}}% Count every question  ***
  \bank% Process file  ***
  \declarenumlist{uniquequestionlist}{1}{\thetotalquestions}% list from 1 to totalquestions inclusive.
  \setcounter{totalquestions}{#2}% Start the count-down
  \RenewEnviron{questionblock}{%
    \stepcounter{questionblock}% Next question
    \ifnum\value{questionblock}=\randomquestion 
      \par% Start new paragraph
      \stepcounter{numberedquestions}
      \arabic{numberedquestions}. \BODY% Print question
    \fi
  }%
  \foreach \uNiQueQ in {1,...,#2} {% Extract #2 random questions
    \setcounter{questionblock}{0}% Start fresh with question block counter
    \pgfmathrandomitem\randomquestion{uniquequestionlist}% Grab random question from list
    \xdef\randomquestion{\randomquestion}% Make random question available globally
    \prunelist{uniquequestionlist}% Remove picked item from list
    \bank% Process file
  }}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,6} {
    \bigskip
    \randomquestionsfrombank{bankA.tex}{6}
  }
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]