# selecting specific questions

Tags: exam, questionnaire

Using the exam package I'm making worksheets for topics. Lets say i make one worksheet with 10 questions however i only want to see questions 2,5,7 and 10. How would i create it so only specific questions are shown on the pdf. So basically the worksheets are like a question bank rather then a whole worksheet/exam paper. Also i would like the shown questions we be numbered 1,2,3... no matter if it is actually 2,5,7...

Comment: Maybe the following can help you: [Generate exam from a question bank?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174872/134144)

Comment: i have just found that but its not really helping me much. i dont really want to change my code too much i was just wondering if there was a specific package or something to like print questions 1-6

Comment: Without changing much of the code, you could comment the questions you don't want to be included and recompile. This way only the uncommented questions appear and are consecutively numbered.

Comment: what do u mean by comment the questions

Comment: Use a `%` sign in front of the question you don't want to show: `\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Question 1
%\question Question 2
\question Question 3
\end{questions}

\end{document}`. will result in the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSdCe.png

Comment: as i have may parts to a question and solutions and everything it just comes out wrong and its a lot of lines of code to %

Comment: `\usepackage{verbatim}` and then `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}`

Comment: sorry what will this do

Comment: Commenting the lines from `\begin{comment}` to `\end{comment}` without need of `%` on each line.... Thought it was obvious by the names... You need to include in this environment questions 1,   3-4,  6 and 8-10... So, only 2,5 and 7 will remain in your active code

Comment: thank you so much that is perfect for me thanks

Comment: Welcome... I could provide a better answer if you had a MWE in your question... We could create an environment for both questions and answers and make this environment a dummy environment for the questions you want to exclude... Happy TeXing anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\iffalse,...,\fi` for skipping the desired questions.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{questions}

    \question Approximate $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \sin x^2 \, dx$ within $.001$ of
    its true value.


    \question Calculate the $$\int_{(5,6)}^{(3,3)} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{l}$$
    for $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)=xy\mathbf{a}_x + (3x-y^2)\mathbf{a}_y$.

    \iffalse
    \question Skipped question.
    \fi

    \question Find the gradient of\\[0.5cm]
    a- $f(x,y,z)=xy^2+2z$\\
    b- $f(r,\phi,z)=2rsin\phi$\\
    c- $f(R,\theta,\phi)=2\theta+R^2$\\

    \question Last question.

    \end{questions}
    \end{document}
```

[image]