# Generate n-many sets of exam by choosing question from m-many banks

Tags: exam, exercisebank

This question is an extension of the topic discussed in [Generate exam from a question bank?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174872/generate-exam-from-a-question-bank).

What I want is as follows: I have three question banks: BankA.tex, BankB.tex and BankC.tex which have three different type of questions. I want to make four sets of questions papers, each set containing, say, two questions from BankA.tex, three questions from BankB.tex and two questions from BankC.tex; I indent to use package `exam` for preparing the question paper(s). I want to have a master file Quiz.tex such that when I run it, I get four different sets of exam each set with the same title (Linear Algebra, Quiz 1\ Date, etc); each set starting on an odd page (good for printing); and the desired number of parts of QuestionX are randomly chosen from BankX.tex where X is either A, B or C. The master file may look like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\pointsinrightmargin

\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,amsbsy,mathtools}

%%%%%Some newcommands, packages, etc.%%%%%


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  {\bfseries Linear Algebra}\\ Quiz,\\ Date .\ 2021.
\end{center}
\noindent Total points: 25\hfill
Time: 12--14 Hrs \medskip

\hrule


\begin{questions}
\question[1 point each] Write the final answer of the following
  question. %Two random questions chosen from QuizA.tex
  \begin{parts}
  \part 
  \part 
  \end{parts}\medskip

\question[2 points each] Solve the following questions.%Three random questions chosen from QuizA.tex
  \begin{parts}
  \part 
  \part
  \part
 \end{parts}\medskip
    
\question[5 points each] Answer the following.%%Two random questions chosen from QuizA.tex
  \begin{parts}
  \part 
  \part
  \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

It is sufficient even if a randomness is replaced by some automatic way-of-choosing-question (e.g. modular arithmetic). I did not succeed in improvising [Generate exam from a question bank?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174872/generate-exam-from-a-question-bank).

Comment: Did you checkout my [exercisebank](https://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank?lang=en) package? It might fit your needs :)