# what does \z mean?

Tags: macros

In some codes I encountered some `\z` command, for example:

```
\pgfmathrandomitem\z{mylist}\z\prunelist{mylist}
```

from this question: [Generating random numbers without repetitions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109619/generating-random-numbers-without-repetitions). What exactly does it mean?

Comment: It's simply the name of a macro.

Comment: just a macro? but if you look at the accepted answer of the linked question, there is no definition of \z... and the code, cut-and-pasted on my editor, works

Comment: `\pgfmathrandomitem` internally makes the necessary definition.

Comment: The answer is **not** accepted, as there's no check by it, @user126154. I'd strongly suggest you mark it as such

Comment: @hd1 The user was referring to 'the accepted answer of the linked question', and the linked question not only has an accepted answer. It isn't the OP's question in any case, so they couldn't accept an answer if they wanted to.

Comment: @user126154 `\z` is a control sequence which is very often preferred by @DavidCarlisle .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's nothing more than a standard macro. Instead of `\z` you could have used `\xxxyyy` or any other valid macro name.

The line

```
\pgfmathrandomitem\z{mylist}
```

simply selects an item from the `mylist` list and stores it in the macro `\z`.

Then

```
\z\prunelist{mylist}
```

shows the item stored in `\z` and removes it from the list.

Comment: so the \z\prunelist{mylist} just prune the listo fo the "macro" \z?

Comment: @user126154 `\z\prunelist{mylist}` removes the item stored in `\z` from the list.

Comment: Ok, now I cut-and-pasted the code, but then I try to use the macro \z elsewhere just by adding \z to some test place and the result is not what I expected

Comment: if I type for instance \pgfmathrandomitem\z{mylist}\z\prunelist{mylist}\z then the result of the last \z is the successor, in the list order, of the firs \z

Comment: i would like indeed store a random element of mylist in a macro that can be used elsewhere

Comment: @user126154 That's exactly what `\pgfmathrandomitem` does: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{mylist}{{one}{two}{three}{four}{five}{six}{seven}}
\pgfmathrandomitem\z{mylist}

\z\z\z


\end{document}`

Comment: @user126154 Perhaps you are trying something like this? `\pgfmathrandomitem\z{mylist}
\edef\xxxx{\z}

\xxxx
\xxxx`

Comment: I'm trying the code in the linked question and then, using this line \pgfmathrandomitem\z{mylist}\z\prunelist{mylist}\z the results of the first and last occurence of the \z are different!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20701/discussion-between-user126154-and-gonzalo-medina).