# Prune list for random order without repetition problem

Tags: random-numbers

I use prune list command from this tutorial [Generating random numbers without repetitions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109619/generating-random-numbers-without-repetitions/109629#109629) for avoid repetitions while generate random sequence. But if I try to use this command in framed box, for example, it doesn't work. As well as in `minipage` environment. Why it happens?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\lengthof[1]{\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\nthof[2]{\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#2@#1\endcsname}

\def\mylist{{one}{two}{three}{four}{five}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{mynum}{\mylist} %Define the list 

\makeatletter
 \def\prunelist#1{% Define prunelist command
  \expandafter\edef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname
     {\the\numexpr\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname-1\relax}
  \count@\pgfmath@randomtemp 
  \loop
   \expandafter\let
   \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\expandafter\endcsname
   \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\numexpr\count@+1\relax\endcsname
   \ifnum\count@<\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname\relax
   \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat}
\makeatother

\newcommand\prnrnd{%
\pgfmathrandomitem{\mynum}{mynum}\mynum %get and print item from list 
\prunelist{mynum} %prune list by selected item}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1, ..., \lengthof{mynum}}%show list
{\par\textit{\nthof{\i}{mynum}}}\\

\fbox{\prnrnd}%extract item (item wasn't extracted!)
\foreach \i in {1, ..., \lengthof{mynum}}%show list
{\par\textit{\nthof{\i}{mynum}}}\\

\prnrnd%extract item
\foreach \i in {1, ..., \lengthof{mynum}}%show list
{\par\textit{\nthof{\i}{mynum}}}\\

\prnrnd%extract item
\foreach \i in {1, ..., \lengthof{mynum}}%show list
{\par\textit{\nthof{\i}{mynum}}}\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need an `\fbox` to show this effect; enclosing `\prnrnd` in braces is sufficient. The explanation is that the changes by `\prunelist` are local to the current group. Outside of the group (the `\fbox` also forms a group) you are back to the old values, the effects of `\prnrnd` have been undone.

Here are two solutions; I recommend the first one.

## Change the list outside of the box

I recommend to modify your `\prnrnd` command such that it does not print the element but just stores it in a macro. Then you can execute it outside of the box and use the stored element inside the box. Replace `\prnrnd` by the following definition.

```
\newcommand\nextrnd[2]%
  {\pgfmathrandomitem{\tmp}{#2}% select random element
   \edef#1{\tmp}% store random element in #1
   \prunelist{#2}%prune list by selected item
  }
```

`\nextrnd{<var>}{<list>}` will pick and remove the next random element from `<list>` and store it in `<var>`.

To make your code easier to read, I also define a macro for listing the contents of the list.

```
\newcommand\showrndlist[1]%
  {\foreach \i in {1, ..., \lengthof{#1}}
     {\par\textit{\nthof{\i}{#1}}}%
   \bigskip
  }
```

Here is the complete code and its output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\lengthof[1]{\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\nthof[2]{\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#2@#1\endcsname}

\newcommand\nextrnd[2]%
  {\pgfmathrandomitem{\tmp}{#2}% select random element
   \edef#1{\tmp}% store random element in #1
   \prunelist{#2}%prune list by selected item
  }
\newcommand\showrndlist[1]%
  {\foreach \i in {1, ..., \lengthof{#1}}
     {\par\textit{\nthof{\i}{#1}}}%
   \bigskip
  }

\makeatletter
 \def\prunelist#1{% Define prunelist command
  \expandafter\edef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname
     {\the\numexpr\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname-1\relax}
  \count@\pgfmath@randomtemp 
  \loop
   \expandafter\let
   \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\expandafter\endcsname
   \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\numexpr\count@+1\relax\endcsname
   \ifnum\count@<\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname\relax
   \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\mylist{{one}{two}{three}{four}{five}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{mynum}{\mylist}% Define the list 

\showrndlist{mynum}

\nextrnd\rnd{mynum}% Store random element in \rnd and remove it from mynum
\fbox{\rnd}% The random element can be put inside a box
\showrndlist{mynum}

\nextrnd\rnd{mynum}% Store random element in \rnd and remove it from mynum
{\rnd}% ... or inside a group
\showrndlist{mynum}

\nextrnd\rnd{mynum}% Store random element in \rnd and remove it from mynum
\rnd
\showrndlist{mynum}
\end{document}
```

> [image] [image] [image] [image]

## Make the effects of `\prunelist` global

You can make the effect of `\prunelist` permanent beyond group ends by replacing

```
\expandafter\edef
```

by

```
\expandafter\xdef
```

and

```
\expandafter\let
```

by

```
\expandafter\global\expandafter\let
```

such that the definition becomes

```
\makeatletter
 \def\prunelist#1{% Define prunelist command
  \expandafter\xdef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname % <<< \edef changed to \xdef
     {\the\numexpr\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname-1\relax}
  \count@\pgfmath@randomtemp 
  \loop
   \expandafter\global\expandafter\let % <<< \expandafter\global added
   \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\expandafter\endcsname
   \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\numexpr\count@+1\relax\endcsname
   \ifnum\count@<\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname\relax
   \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I'm beginner in LaTeX and still not quite understand the core mechanism. But I try :). Thanks alot for explanation.

Comment: @Konstantin I have found a better solution; see my modified answer.

Comment: Do you mean `\expandafter\xdef` instead of the more complicated `\expandafter\global\expandafter\edef`?

Comment: I just want to write random print command with the list as argument. Thanks, first solution exactly what I need.