# Print arguments of a macro in a random order

Tags: macros, random-numbers

I have the following (simplified) LaTeX code that simply prints all its arguments.

```
\newcommand{\mm}[4]{#1 #2 #3 #4}
```

Now, I would like the arguments to be printed in a **random order**, e.g., `#2 #1 #4 #3`. 
Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. You can add syntax highlighting to your post by selecting the code and clicking the button marked `{}`. Blocks are then indented by four spaces, inline code is put within backticks (`\``).

Comment: Are you trying to randomize answer for tests? If so the `exam` or `esami` classes can be of help avoiding to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Is [Selecting random elements from a comma separated list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86165/selecting-random-elements-from-a-comma-separated-list) close enough for your purposes?

Comment: It is indeed for a test. The problem is that I need to preserve this syntax for backward compatibility, i.e., I need to be able to call my macro this way `\mm{Text1}{Text2}{Text3}{Text4}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this code is doing what I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\input random
\newcount\randnum
\newcommand\argrandom[4]{%
    \def\listarg{{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
    \setrannum\randnum{1}{4}%
    \StrChar{\listarg}{\randnum}[\mychar]
    \StrDel{\listarg}{\mychar}[\listarg]\mychar\ 
    \setrannum\randnum{1}{3}%
    \StrChar{\listarg}{\randnum}[\mychar]\mychar\ 
    \StrDel{\listarg}{\mychar}[\listarg]%
    \setrannum\randnum{1}{2}%
    \StrChar{\listarg}{\randnum}[\mychar]\mychar\ 
    \StrDel{\listarg}{\mychar}%
}
\begin{document}
\argrandom{un}{deux}{trois}{quatre}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to nino_ras on [this link](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1392307/autres-langages/autres-langages/latex/afficher-parametres-d-macro-ordre-aleatoire/) for answering my question.